# Python/Raspberry pi 3: comparing strftime time to integer time in database

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi3

My goal is to have a simple if statement that compares the actual time displayed on my raspberry pi (for example, 5pm reads 1700 on my pi), with an integer that the user has defined and then stored in my database. (for example, the user inputted a military time reading of 5pm which in military time is 1700, once submitted, the integer value 1700 gets stored in my database.

If the users inputted time is equal to the actual time, then I want to print hello world or something of the sort.

I think the problem I am having is that the database integer is not properly retuning a value that can be compared to a strftime("%H%M") command... any suggestions?

When I print the value of userin_time1 (variable assigned to retrieve newest value in database, which is currently 2018), the return value is:

(2018L,)

the command I use to get the actual time on my pi is strftime("%H%M") this returns the value:

2018

I was thinking that maybe the parenthesis and L and comma was messing my logic up so I edited the strftime function to look like this:

strftime("(%H%ML,)")

in doing this, the code compiles and returns the value:

(2018L,)

When I assign both the pi's time (strftime function) and the users inputted time (userin_time1 function) to a new variable x and y respectively, and compare them using this statement:

if(x==y):
   print 'hello world'

the code runs but when the condition is met (the times line up with each other perfectly) nothing happens...

Comment: Can you print  and edit your question with the return value from database?

Comment: What is the desired output for 2018? Is it '08:18PM'?

Comment: yes, the conversion from 2018 would become 08:18PM.. but the reason I went with military time is because not only is my pi's clock in military time, but I also figured these integer numbers would be easier to store in my database and compare logically than regular time

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime

d = datetime.strptime("2018", "%H%M")
db_time = d.strftime("%I:%M%p") #results '08:18PM'
current_time = strftime("%I:%M:%p", gmtime())
if db_time == current_time:
    print "Time matched"
else:
    print "Time not matched"
```

Is this something you are expecting?

Comment: I am not sure this would accomplish what I am seeking, for I am just trying to use an if statement to compare the actual time with a user inputted time and have a function run if these conditions are true... not to convert military time to regular time

Comment: Can you show piece of code what there is problem for the input and expecting output?

Comment: x = userin_time1  ## This pulls database value, which is (2018L,)                         y = strftime("(%H%ML,)") ##this gets time from pi, returns (2018L,)                   if(x==y):                                                                                                                      print 'hello world'     ##if condition is true, print hello world

Comment: sorry for lazy formatting, I am new to stack overflow and don't know how to add code into a comment... I am certain formatting is correct though in my code

Comment: You are saying `x = '(2018L,)'`, `y = '(2018L,)'`, ` if x == y:    print 'hello world'`. Then what is the problem?

Comment: I think the problem is that x is a tuple that is pulled from a database. so when trying to compare the tuple to the actual time nothing happens.. but their is no error which is what confuses me... the program runs but nothing happens

Comment: Can you edit your question and write your actual code?